# How to get the 'selectedIndex' property of a Select using JavaScript in Python with selenium

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to execute a JavaScript script to get the index of a selected option from a **Select** webelement like so:

```
@property
def selected_option_index(self):
    index = driver.execute_script('arguments[0].selectedIndex', self.select_field)
    return index
```

But the result is **None**

The same happens when I try a more direct approach, like:

```
index = driver.execute_script('document.querySelector(\'select[name="vehicleType"]\').selectedIndex')
```

[image: Debugging result]

However, when I try running the following JavaScript:

```
typeSelectIndex = document.querySelector('select[name="vehicleType"]').selectedIndex
```

in the developer tools - console, the result is ok:

```
15
```

[image: Developer Tools query result]

How should the Python code be structured to obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing return keyword in the javascript. please try the followings.

```
@property
def selected_option_index(self):
    index = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].selectedIndex', self.select_field)
    return index
```

or

```
index = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector(\'select[name="vehicleType"]\').selectedIndex')
```